# cloning html element doesnt seem to have prototype methods

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to clone the contents of a modal before it disappears.

basically when the ok button is clicked it passes a clone of object to function like so

```
$ok.onclick = function(e){
        if(params.ok)
            var $cont = $content.cloneNode(true);
            params.ok($cont);
        closeSlert($slert);
    }
```

however later I am trying to use getElementById() but it returns that this is not a function

I thought that Element.clone clones the prototype as well.

just incase someone thinks to suggest $content.cloneNode(true) that doesnt seem to pass prototype methods either. is there a way to reapply the prototype methods or better yet clone them with the element

here is the entire slert function

```
function genSlert(params) {
    var slerts = getSlerts(),
        $slert = document.createElement('div'),
        $buttons = document.createElement('div'),
        $ok = document.createElement('button'),
        $cancel = document.createElement('button'),
        $content = document.createElement('div');
    for(var i = 0; i < slerts.length; i++){
        slideUp(slerts[i]);
    }
    $buttons.className = 'buttons';
    $content.innerHTML = params.content;
    $content.className = 'content';
    $slert.className = 'slert';
    $slert.appendChild($content);
    $slert.appendChild($buttons);
    $buttons.appendChild($cancel);
    $buttons.appendChild($ok);
    $ok.innerHTML = 'OK';
    $cancel.innerHTML = 'CANCEL';
    wrapper.appendChild($slert);
    wrapper.classList.remove('hidden');
    document.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
    $cancel.onclick = function (e) {
        if (params.cancel) {
            params.cancel(e);
        }
        //close modal
        closeSlert($slert);
    }
    $ok.onclick = function(e){
        if(params.ok){
            var $cont = $content.cloneNode(true);
            params.ok($cont);
        }
        closeSlert($slert);
    }

}
```

Comment: code shown is far too incomplete to assess your problem

Comment: what else do you need $content is a HTMLDIVElement

Comment: before edit you had an undefined function

Comment: yes. I have also tried to console.log $cont.prototype that return undefined, although so does console.log($content.prototype);

Comment: strangely enough querySelector works but getElementById does not I though they were Both prototyped from Element. I prefer getELementById as it is usually much faster